# Remote Notification volume level differs from sound played in app

Tags: ios

I have to play notification sound in my app when someone calls the user. When I put app in minimised state, push notification get displayed with custom sound that I have assigned to it. But when my app is in foreground, same custom sound volume level does not follow ringer sound level. I have used audio services for playing sound when app is in foreground. But there is difference in volume levels of notification sound and same sound played by audio service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this, by using `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound` to play `SystemSound`. What I did wrong was the method which used to play `SystemSound`. There are two methods can be used to play `SystemSound` i.e `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` and `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound`. I was using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` which does not follow volume level which is used by Remote Notification. So now I am using `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound`, which plays sound at same level as Remote Notification.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right, there is intended difference between those two. And here is the deal.. the sound level of a Remote notification is driven by the 'Ringer and Alerts' volume level. While on the other hand the in-app played audio is affected by 'Music and Audio' volume level.

Note: If you want to play the sound at the 'Ringer and Alert' volume level you could use `AudioToolbox framework` and play a System/Alert sound (but keep in mind that this will play only short sounds up to 30 seconds)

Here is the Apple Docs for it: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlayAlertSound

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Actually I have already solved this, but didn't got time to update here. As you said I was already using SystemSound to play custom sound. But what I did wrong was the method which used to play SystemSound. There are two methods can be used to play SystemSound i.e AudioServicesPlaySystemSound and AudioServicesPlayAlertSound. I was using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound which does not follow volume level which is used by Remote Notification. So now I am using AudioServicesPlayAlertSound, which plays sound at same level as Remote Notification.